# Compilation error with Mocha react native router

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, enzyme

I have raised it as an issue [here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/694). I was able to unit test - shallow render and test a react native component, however when I introduced react-native-router flux to the project, started failing with errors

```
> test@0.0.1 test /Users/sseshac/src/personal/test/app/test
> mocha --require react-native-mock/mock.js --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive test/*.js

/Users/sseshac/src/personal/test/app/test/node_modules/react-native-router-flux/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Actions from './src/Actions';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous functi
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Babel to use the `es2015` preset, either by creating a `.babelrc` file in your project directory containing the following:

```
{ "presets": ["es2015"] }
```

Or adding this to your `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "babel": {
    "presets": ["es2015"] 
  }
}
```

See also [this page](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/).

The above requires that `babel-preset-2015` is installed:

```
$ npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Comment: That unfortunately did not solve the problem for me. I have react-native and es2015 presets in my .babelrc now. Still the same error

Comment: Could it be caused by the `--require` argument? Not sure if `--compilers` is also applied to those.